# How should i get matching sub-objects from nested json object

Tags: json, nested, javascript-objects

I have an obj like this:

```
var obj = { thing1 : { name: 'test', value: 'testvalue1'},
            thing2 : { name: 'something', thing4: {name:'test', value: 'testvalue2'}},
          }
```

I want to write a function like findByName(obj, 'test').It returns all the matching sub-objects with the same name.  So it should return: 
{ name: 'test', value: 'testvalue1'}
{name:'test', value: 'testvalue2'}

Right now this is what i have:

```
function findByName(obj, name) {
    if( obj.name === name ){
      return obj;
    }
    var result, p;
    for (p in obj) {
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof obj[p] === 'object' ) {
            result = findByName(obj[p], name);
            if(result){
              return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

obviously it only return the first matching.. how to improve this method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the results into an array and make the function return an array.

Also, do a sanity check whether the object is null or undefined to avoid errors.
Here is your code modified.
 Note: I have also modified the parent object ,which is "obj", by adding a "name" property with value "test" so the result should have the parent object in the result as well.

```
function findByName(obj, name) {
    var result=[], p;
    if(obj == null || obj == undefined)
        return result;
    if( obj.name === name ){
      result.push(obj);
    }
    for (p in obj) {
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof obj[p] === 'object') {
            newresult = findByName(obj[p], name);
            if(newresult.length>0){

               //concatenate the result with previous results found;
               result=result.concat(newresult);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
var obj = { thing1 : { name: 'test', value: 'testvalue1'},
            thing2 : { name: 'something', thing4: {name:'test', value: 'testvalue2'}}, 
name:'test' //new property added

          }

//execute
findByName(obj,"test");
```

Run this in your console and upvote if this helps you.